# Is redistribution of the C++ 2008 Redistributable Package forbidden?

Tags: visual-c++, redistributable

A naive mind would expect you're allowed to redistribute a package called **redistributable**. And a lot of software ships with the redist package and install them. But the software license terms of the *Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package* clearly state: "You may not ... publish the software for others to copy".

I've read the answer to [Can Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package be freely redistributed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2643760/1210825), but unfortunately the only source of information there is a 3rd party how-to that has no legal value.

Is there a legal way to ship the C++ Redistributable Package or do we have to point customers to the download page?

Background:
We have permission to ship 3rd party dlls with our product but no influence otherwise on those dlls. These dlls need the 2008 c++ redistributable package. If I understood the situation correctly, we'd need a VS2008 license, to ship the microsoft-dlls with our application and create a clean setup procedure.

The [Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=29) I'm talking about.

Comment: Redistributing is completely different from publishing.  There are plenty of web sites that offer a Windows DLL for downloading.  Anybody that *trusts* such a website to deliver an actual original copy of the DLL that hasn't been messed with has been asleep for the past 10 years.  Of course Microsoft doesn't want these sites to do this.  They already have one anyway.  Write an installer, the merge files you need are already on your machine.

Comment: Maybe somewhat late: I just misunderstood the legal terms. This was the right answer for me.  But I could not mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get redistribution permission from a Windows SDK. The Win SDK for Windows 7 with .NET 4 SDK contains the following files for MSVC++ 2010:

```
\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Redist\VC
    vcredist_ia64.exe
    vcredist_x64.exe
    vcredist_x86.exe
```

And the redist.txt file indicates:

> Subject to the license terms for the software, you may redistribute the files listed below unmodified as a part of your installation package: [followed by the above list]

I don't have an earlier SDK installed at the moment, but I'd guess that an SDK released around 2009 might have the VC++ 2008 redistributable runtime files you're looking for.

---

Update:

The [Windows SDK for Win 7 with .NET 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=71deb800-c591-4f97-a900-bea146e4fae1) does contain runtimes for VC++ 2008, but the redist permissions are not for the `vcredist_xxx.exe` format.  That SDK provides redist rights for the raw DLLs and manifests to be used as part of your applications local directory structure. That still might give you what you need to install your application without having to use MSI and the merge files for the VC runtime.

> For your convenience, we have provided the following folders for use
>   when redistributing VC++ runtime files. Subject to the license terms
>   for the software, you may redistribute the folder (unmodified) in the
>   application local folder as a sub-folder with no change to the folder
>   name. You may also redistribute all the files (*.dll and *.manifest)
>   within a folder, listed below the folder for your convenience, as an
>   entire set.
>
> ```
> \Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\
>      Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
>      msvcm90.dll
>      msvcp90.dll
>      msvcr90.dll
> ```
>
> etc...

Comment: That sounds like the solution. I'll continue in that direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get a VS license, ask one of your 3rd party dll provider to create a setup that includes the redistributable, then include the dll provider's setup in your installer.

It is the 3rd party dll provider's responsibility to make sure their dll work on machines without the redistributables after installing. The fact that none of your providers seems to be shipping with the redistributable dependency is surprising.

Comment: The 3rd party basically doesn't care. They want their dlls to work with their product. We're allowed to offer them as downloads but they see no further responsibility. If someone wants support he has to purchase the 3rd party main product, which comes with an installer and necessary microsoft-dlls.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Express Editions come with the necessary license, too. You'll have to register them with Microsoft, but they're free-as-in-beer.